# Passing React Hook to functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I'm looking to create a functional component that takes in a hook and its Set function as parameters and constructs an associated input using those fields (along with some other fields). Running into issues with passing in spread operators (as advised in "Learning React, 2nd edition"). Relevant snippets below, help appreciated!

1. Generic function that takes in an initial value and returns a new hook and its setValue function:

```
    export const useInput = (initialValue) => {
      const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
      return [
        { value, onChange: (e) => setValue(e.target.value) },
        () => setValue(initialValue),
      ];
    };
```

2. The hook to be used:

```
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useInput("");
```

3. The functional component (after some cleanup)

```
      const MyInputComp = (props) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <input
              className="blah-blah-blah"
              {props.obj}   // *ERROR*
              type="text"
              placeholder={props.placeholder}
              required={props.required}
            />
          </div>
        );
      };
```

4. Here's how the component is invoked:

```
    <MyInputComp
        text="First Name"
        obj={...firstName}  // *ERROR*
        placeholder="Jon"
        required={true}
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are not consuming the input value and updater correctly.

The are returned as `{ value, onChange: (e) => setValue(e.target.value) }`

but you are passing singly as `obj`

```
obj={...firstName}
```

and

```
const MyInputComp = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        className="blah-blah-blah"
        {props.obj}   // *ERROR*
        type="text"
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        required={props.required}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

## Solution

Spread the `value` and `onChange` props into the underlying `input`

```
const MyInputComp = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        className="blah-blah-blah"
        {...props.obj} // <-- spreads value & onChange props
        type="text"
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        required={props.required}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Since `MyInputComp` appears to be simply proxying some props you can spread them all in *and then* destructure what you need.

```
const MyInputComp = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        className="blah-blah-blah"
        {...props} // <-- spread all passed props
        type="text"
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Use

```
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useInput("");

<MyInputComp
    text="First Name"
    {...firstName} // <-- spread to input
    placeholder="Jon" // <-- spread to input
    required={true} // <-- spread to input
/>
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks not just for the solution, but for the guidance on how to improve it further.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do couple of changes. First spread the `props.obj` object so that input element under the hood can take `value` and `onChange` props. Such as

```js
const MyInputComp = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        className="blah-blah-blah"
        {...props.obj}
        type="text"
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        required={props.required}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Then render the `MyInputComp` like that

```
 <MyInputComp
      text="First Name"
      obj={firstName}
      placeholder="Jon"
      required={true}
      onChange={handleNameChange}
/>
```

Also in the custom `useInput` hook the change function should be like

```
(value) => setValue(value)
```

instead of `() => setValue(initialValue)`